# Pandas, Sort_Values not sorting properly

Tags: pandas

I am trying to sort my dataframe.

```
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by='PTS', ascending=False)
print(df_sorted['PTS'])
```

It does not work properly, my dataframe is 93 rows and I am not getting it sorted.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your column should be string let us convert it to numeric first

```
df.PTS = pd.to_numeric(df.PTS)
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by='PTS', ascending=False)
```